# Why does tkinter block when ending this thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a worker thread that manages further threads/processes and communicates with my tkinter GUI thread.

For this I have a GUI class that inherits from `tkinter.Frame` with a simple start button, a progressbar and a variable label. When pressing the start button the worker thread gets started. This thread runs entirely separately from the GUI (therefore no `.join()` necessary after creating the worker thread) and sends back its progress via a tkinter Event (`tkinter.event_generate()`) and a Queue (`queue.Queue()`).

Now this works well, and even letting the thread complete works well. However if you try to abort the thread by setting a `threading.Event()` and join the thread to wait for a safe exit, the GUI hangs and only continues if join's timer runs out.

When setting the `threading.Event()` I would expect the worker thread to generate a `<<MyEventAborted>>`-event almost immediately, then to return the `run()/start()`-methods and thereby to stop existing. This should resolve the `join()`-call immediately. Why does it not work like that? I'm using python 3.9.12

```py
import queue
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class GUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.init_elements()


    def init_elements(self):

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_worker)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.label = tk.StringVar(value="nothing yet")
        ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.label).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="E", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.progress = tk.DoubleVar(0)
        ttk.Progressbar(
            self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate', maximum=100, variable=self.progress
        ).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="WE", padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.bind("<<MyEventUpdate>>", self.on_update)
        self.bind("<<MyEventFinished>>", self.on_finished)
        self.bind("<<MyEventAborted>>", self.on_aborted)
        self.com_queue = queue.Queue()

    def on_update(self, event):
        progress = self.progress.get()
        self.progress.set(progress+1)
        self.label.set(f"Task {(self.com_queue.get()):.0f}/100")

    def on_finished(self, event):
        self.label.set("Finished!")
        self.button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_worker)

    def on_aborted(self, event):
        self.label.set("Aborted!")
        self.button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_worker)

    def start_worker(self):
        self.progress.set(0)
        self.button.configure(text="Stop", command=self.stop_worker)
        self.worker_thread = MyStoppableThread(queue=self.com_queue, tk_gui=self)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def stop_worker(self):
        self.worker_thread.stop()
        self.worker_thread.join(timeout=3)
        self.button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_worker)

    
class MyStoppableThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, tk_gui, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue
        self.tk_gui = tk_gui
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
    
    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        task_num = 0
        while task_num < 100:

            if self.stopped():
                self.tk_gui.event_generate("<<MyEventAborted>>", when="now")
                print("Stopped")
                return
            
            time.sleep(0.1)
            task_num += 1
            self.queue.put(task_num)
            self.tk_gui.event_generate("<<MyEventUpdate>>", when="tail")
        self.tk_gui.event_generate("<<MyEventFinished>>", when="tail")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize GUI and tkinter
    root = tk.Tk()
    GUI(root).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NSWE")

    # Start GUI
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you called the `join()` inside the event handler without ensuring there will be no more  Tck/Tk calls in the worker thread. When you called the `join()`, the Tcl/Tk event loop was blocked and the subsequent Tcl/Tk call(`event_generate()`) on the worker thread couldn't finish. (A deadlock occurred.)

So, join the thread at the `on_finished()` and the `on_aborted()`. Also don't let the thread wait until the event(`<<MyEventAborted>>`) is processed by specifying the `when` as 'now', to avoid another deadlock.

Correct like the following.

```
...
class GUI(tk.Frame):
    ...
    def on_finished(self, event):
        ...
        self.join_worker()

    def on_aborted(self, event):
        ...
        self.join_worker()
    ...
    def stop_worker(self):
        self.worker_thread.stop()

    def join_worker(self):
        self.worker_thread.join()
        self.button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_worker)
...
class MyStoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
                self.tk_gui.event_generate("<<MyEventAborted>>", when="tail")
        ...
```

Also, note that there's no meaning to using the `threading.Event` if you don't call `wait()`.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I wasn't aware that .join() in the Tk-thread would stop the worker thread from generating any events.